# T-SQL : Using { fn NOW() } in WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was reviewing some SQL queries and I saw a select statement that looked like this

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE (dbo.mytable.[Date] < { fn NOW() })
```

What is the purpose of using a WHERE statement like this?

Wouldn't be easier to use a simple GETDATE()?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic183904-8-1.aspx

GETDATE() is a T-SQL specific function which returns the current system date
and time. The SQL standard equivalent is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which is
applicable in T-SQL as well. The {fn Now()} is an ODBC canonical function
which can be used in T-SQL since the OLE DB provider for SQL Server supports
them. There are no notable performance difference between these though. You
can also use canonical format like :

```
SELECT {fn CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()} AS "date & time",
       {fn CURRENT_DATE()} AS "date only",
       {fn CURRENT_TIME()} AS "time only" ;
```

Comment: I can't access to the mentionned article. It ask me to log in.

Comment: Sign up, it's free.  The relevant part is what I posted in my post here.